# Restrict Particle force influence by Area

Tags: particles

For a crowd simulation, created by using force fields(**Force**) to generate **limited particle displacement** [simulating a "PARTING EFFECT"],how  can one **restrict influence of the Effector** to only the ***particles close to the Effector Object*** and not have any influence on the particles which are ***away from the Effector***?

In this simulation[Gravity=OFF],the force field is set to the **lowest effecting Strength(= 0.1)** to cause any resonable particle displacement,but **all particles are getting affected**.

There is no effect on setting **Field Weights by Weight Painting the particle emitting Object** and with no way to assign **separate Vertex groups of Emitter Regions** in the same particle emitting object,how can one cause two different Particle behaviours **in the same Particle System and using the same Force Field?**
[image: Field Forces]
[image: Particle Simulation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Falloff on your effector, enter a power value (here 4.3) and limit it's maximum distance to whatever suit your scene.

[image]

Also add a drag force, and set it up like in the screenshot, to avoid the cubes flying away after they were pushed (the drag isn't shown in my gif just to be clear)[image].

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution by @Arthur Blaquart can be accepted as an Answer,there is still some **undesired spilling of the particles beyond the resting plane's particle perimeter** .No matter how much the Drag/Falloff is varied, the Force Field  **spills the particles beyond the plane** (for lower values) or completely **stalls their movement**(for higher values).

As I had already achieved the desired result,thought I would share the **additional steps required to camouflage this spillover.**

**1**.**Separate region into areas** which are affected and which remain unaffected by the particle system -**Affected and Unaffected**.This can be done in Edit mode  by selecting the necessary Faces and using Split(Y) & Separate By Loose parts(P) commands.
[image]

**2**.Create **Separate Particle Systems** for the 2 regions. Main difference in the Particle Systems being Force Fields Weights -
**Affected Region - 1.000**
**Unaffected Region - 0.000**
Also ,refer the image below for additional particle system settings(**Force Field => Force-Strength = 1 )**
[image: Affected Particle System Settings]
[image]

**3**.Now when the Effector "Sphere" affects the particle "Cubes" , the **additional spillover gets camouflaged** ,as they hide within the particles created in the Unaffected plane.Inorder to morph the ground plane's split,add an additional plane underneath it (with same material).
[image]